# Singleton class return two different singleton objects

Tags: java, singleton

I want to design a class which should return a singleton of some third party object. 
For e.g., I want to create a singleton of 3rd party B class object. Below is the design I have made.

```
public class A{

private static A A = null;
private static B B = null;

private A() {

    B = code to instantiate B Object;

}

public static synchronized A getAInstance() {

    if(A ==null){
        synchronized(A.class){
            if(A == null){
                 A = new A();
            }
        }
    }
    return A;
}
public B getB(){
    return B;
}
```

}

Can you please help me is this a proper singleton

Comment: I don't see anything that prevents other code from also instantiating objects of class B (not sure if that is a problem or not).

Comment: `B` shouldn't be `static` if you're treating it as a member of the single `A` instance (as you seem to be with that `getB` instance method). While `getB` will work with a `static` `B`, it's significantly misleading.

Comment: You don't need a second `synchronized` block (on the same monitor) inside of the `synchronized` method (maybe lose it on the method).

Comment: @Thilo: Good point about `B`, I've fixed the comment.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Well, that constructor is only run once, so that's probably fine. (But someone else could also make B instances)

Comment: If you *do* lose the `synchronized` on the method, you're relying on the [double-checked locking pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java). That's fine in Java 5 and higher, but only if what you're initializing is `volatile`.

Comment: @Thilo right! I didn't saw it, as the code is somehow weird in many places...

Comment: I'm not much of a Java-head anymore, but wouldn't simply `public class A { public static final B B = /*...code to create B...*/; }` do the trick? If `A`'s sole reason for being is to provide a single `B` instance, it will only be loaded (and thus its static initializer run) if it's actually used...

Comment: Using reflection it is still possible to create an instance. Are there any reflections being used in your code?

Comment: Good point to remove method synchronisation. I just want to restrict the access to B only through A. Also, we are not using any reflections in our code

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have a single instance of a third party class. First of all it is a good practice to access third party obj via wrapper class obj,(clean code handbook of agile software craftsmanship chapter8), in your case class b is wrapped by class a.
In order to make a single instance of class b you can just make it an instance variable of class a and then make the class a singleton, code bellow

```
Public class A{

private static A A = null;
private B B = null;

private A() {
  B = code to instantiate B Object;
 }

public static synchronized A getAInstance() {

if(A ==null){
    synchronized(A.class){
        if(A == null){
             A = new A();
        }
    }
  }
  return A;
 }

public B getB(){
  return B;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have this structure. No explicit synchrnoization required, just leave it to JVM.

```
public class A {

 private static class BInstanceHolder {
    B BInstance = new B();
}

private A(){}

public static B getB(){

   return BInstanceHolder.BInstance;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to have one copy of B, just do it that way!
You dont even need a Singleton of Class A.
So you could try:

```
public final class A{

  private A(){}

  private static B instance;

  static{
    instance = code to instantiate B Object
  }

  public static synchronized B getInstance() {
      return B;
  }
}
```

The static Block will create a instance of B when the Class is first mentioned and will instantiate the instance. The constructor will prevent the A from being made, but you can still access the only instance of B.